# I'm trying to implement the find key function in a general search tree where a node can have any number of children. The code is given below

Tags: tree, find, binary-search-tree

shared_ptr<node<T,S>> Tree<T,S>::findKeyHelper(shared_ptr<node<T,S>> currNode, T key) {

```
if (currNode->key==key){
    return currNode;
}

else {

    if (currNode->child==NULL){

        if (currNode->sibling==NULL){
            return NULL;
        }

        else {
            findKeyHelper(currNode->sibling,key);
        }
    }

    else {
         findKeyHelper(currNode->child,key);
    }

}
```

}

how do I make the function search other subtrees after 1 subtree has been exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using **left-child, right-sibling representation of tree** to implement constant number of children. Your procedure needs several modifications. Other subtrees can be searched using recursion. Recursion works because subtrees have the same structure as tree itself (subtrees are small instances of tree).

```
if (currNode!= NULL && currNode->key == key){ 
    return currNode;
}
```

You need to check `current` pointer. If `current == NULL`, then `current->key` will give error that you can't dereference `NULL` pointer.

```
else {
    if(currNode->sibling != NULL)
        findKeyHelper(currNode->sibling, key);

    if(currNode->child != NULL)
        findKeyHelper(currNode->child, key);
}
```

Procedure first checks if `current` is `NULL` or not. If it is, it terminates; otherwise, searches for a value in `current` node. If it finds, return `current`; If not, it must be sure that whether there is any siblings or child to search for or not. If parts solves this. Notice that recursive calls happen when subtrees are not `NULL`. Your problem is mainly solved in `else` part. 
**EDIT:** I revised your procedure and got the why it's not working. You're calling recursive procedure on **siblings** only when the child of node is `NULL`. But it's not the case: you're not visiting the siblings when the child of a node is not `NULL`. This is the problem and you can solve it by extracting

```
if (currNode->sibling==NULL){
     return NULL;
}
else {
     findKeyHelper(currNode->sibling,key);
}
```

out of `if-block` statement and your program will work. Now the correct procedure will look like:

```
if (currNode!= NULL && currNode->key==key){
    return currNode;
}

if(currNode->child == NULL) ;

else {
    findKeyHelper(currNode->child, key);
}

if (currNode->sibling==NULL)
       ;
else
    findKeyHelper(currNode->sibling, key);
```

Since empty-body if statements do nothing, you can delete them, and that's what I did above.